# Docker> postgresql9.6 error

Tags: postgresql, docker, centos

I am using docker to install postgresql 9.6 from centos7 image. I got an error while initialize the postgresql and also problem with this service.

```
 sh-4.2# usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
    Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
    failed to find PGDATA setting in postgresql-9.6.service
 sh-4.2# systemctl start postgresql-9.6.service
    Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: This could probably be because `systemd` is not present in the centos7 image. You may find this link (https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/) useful.

Comment: systemd installed already. but cannot find any solution

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile?

Comment: I just pull the centos:7 image then installed package